# Does LastPass browser extension store my passwords locally on browser storage?

Tags: passwords, google-chrome-extensions, lastpass, firefox-extensions

Does LastPass browser extension store my passwords locally on browser storage? Is it safe?

LastPass browser extension working insights required to confirm safe & secure logins to web application forms.

Comment: yes, it does/is.

Answer (score -1):

> The data is located in the following places, depending on your
>   operating system and browser(s).
>
> For Windows OS:
>
> **Internet Explorer & Firefox:**
>
> - `%AppData%\..\LocalLow\LastPass\` or
> - `%AppData%\..\Local Settings\Application Data\LastPass\`
>
> **Google Chrome*:**
>
> - `%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\UserData\Default\databases\chrome-extension_hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd_0\`
>
> **Edge:**
>
> - `%AppData%\..\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\`
>
> **Opera:**
>
> - `%LocalAppData%\Opera\Opera\widgets\wuid-*\pstorage\*\*\`
>
> ---
>
> *If LastPass Binary Component was present when you last trusted your computer, data will be found in `%AppData%\..\LocalLow\LastPass\` or
>   `%AppData%\..\Local Settings\Application Data\LastPass\`
>
> ---
>
> Please also check here:
>   **[https://lastpass.com/safesec](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=6926)** how LastPass is
>   safe.

[image: 0]